# Appear an input text when checkbox is selected?

Tags: javascript, jsf, primefaces

I need to choose different items from a checkbox and for each item that I select I need to appear an input text but I'm not sure how can I do that with primefaces or should I use another thing? I already load the manycheckbox with items from my database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve that you can use JavaScript, I think it is the simplest way to appear an element when you select a checkbox.

You can do that by using plain JavaScript or you can integrate your app with JQuery for example.

Maybe you should do something like `onclick = someFunction()` and withing `someFunction()` you can change the visibility of the element you want to appear.

If you need more help you can post your code here so that we can review it.